# WhatsApp Web/Desktop: Missing messages

Tags: whatsapp

I recently moved from my Android phone to my new iPhone XR. As part of this relocation I transferred all my previous WhatsApp chats from my Android to my iPhone using a third party tool. It seems that all chats have been properly restored to my iPhone. But, when using WhatsApp Web/Desktop I see none of my previously sent messages and messages longer ago are missing at all. When receiving/sending new messages everything is fine as they do also appear in WhatsApp Web/Desktop.

Any idea why older messages are missing in WhatsApp Web/Desktop?

I have the latest iOS version and latest WhatsApp version installed.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What third-pary tool have you used? Have you already check their help/faq?

Comment: I have used Wondershare Dr.Fone; I have read their FAQ and contacted their support without success.

Comment: Since that tool is a tool installable on Windows and Mac but it's pointed to mobile phone users I suggest you to post your question on site where installable apps are on-topic like [su] or on sites where mobile apps are on-topic like [apple.se] and [android.se]